# VSCode launch ASP.NET Core app on a specific port

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

From launch.json, what is the correct way to launch an ASP.NET Core on a specific port? For instance, when I run my .NET Core app, VS Code, hosts it on localhost:5000, but I instead want to host it on localhost:5050.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can config it via environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS`

macOS:

```
export ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5050
```

windows:

```
set ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5050
```

or add this to launch.json

```
  "env": {
    "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5050"
  }
```

If you don't want to specify the hostname, you can use * instead

```
http://*:5050
```

Comment: The * didn't work for me.  I ended up with `http://[::]:5050/`  Putting in the full URL worked great.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Where to put this env element?

Comment: @KokHowTeh In VSCode for Windows I've put the env element in launch.json file. The path to the env element looks like { configurations: [ { env: { } } ] }. Works for me.

Comment: Thank u. It works for me. How can I start the page with a swagger. etc. "https://localhost:5050/swagger". Thanks