# Change VS Code default IP when launching dotnet application

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code to create my first dotnet server side application.
When I launch it, it always opens a new tab in a browser with https://localhost:7258/ as URL.

Is there a setting I can change so that localhost can be replaced with my computer's current IP address?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949752/vscode-launch-asp-net-core-app-on-a-specific-port

Comment: Thank you so much @MilosStojanovic, it did the trick :-) If you add this as an answer, rather a than comment, I can mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is following steps from answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949752/vscode-launch-asp-net-core-app-on-a-specific-port).
Summed up: You have to set env variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to url that you want to be used. You can do it using cmd or you can set it in `launch.json` file under the key `env`.